# how to set datasource in jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have datasource.the code is as below:

```
public class DataSource {
    Connection connection = null;
    BasicDataSource bdsource = new BasicDataSource();

    public DataSource() {
        bdsource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        bdsource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName");
        bdsource.setUsername("UserName");
        bdsource.setPassword("PassWord");

    }

    public Connection createConnection() {

        Connection con = null;

        try {

            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("Can't create a new connection");
            } else {
                con = bdsource.getConnection();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

I need to display some data from database on jsp. So how can i set the the datasource in jsp without letting the world know the username, password and database name in jsp?

Comment: Anyways no one will be able to see your Username, Password from Datasource, until you print in JSP

Comment: but they can access my jsp page itself no.. usually its not a good practice to keep all this in jsp. Have learnt it from stack itself

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSTL sql:setDataSource Tag</title>
</head>
<body>

<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/TEST"
     user="user_id"  password="mypassword"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" sql="..." var="result" />

</body>
</html>
```

More detail refer the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html)

Answer (score 0):

Connection class

```
    public class ConnectBean {
    private Connection con;
    private static ConnectBean instance;
    private ConnectBean() throws Exception {
        try {
            String driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.1.1:1521:base";
            String user = "user";
            String password = "pass";            
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
    public static synchronized  ConnectBean getInstance () throws Exception {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ConnectBean();
        }
        return instance;         
    }
    public Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }
}
```

JSP page

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

<h2 align="center"><font color="#FF00FF"><strong>Select query in JSP</strong></font></h2>
<table align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
<tr>

</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#008000">
<td><b>Id</b></td>
<td><b>Name</b></td>
</tr>
<%
    Statement stmt = evg.oracle_jta.connection.ConnectBean.getInstance().getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM your_table");
    out.println("<html><body><h2>The Select query has following results : </h2>");

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        out.println("<tr bgcolor='#8FBC8F'>");
        out.println("<td>"+resultSet.getString("id") + "</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+resultSet.getString("name") + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
    }    
%>  
</table>
```